# Spring Json property mapping an array of Strings to a field in an array of Objects

Tags: java, json, spring, list

If I'm expecting this in the response body of a GET request:

```
   "aPort" : 80,
   "someIps" :
      [
         "10.2.1.1",
         "1.2.3.4"
      ],
```

Could I use the @JsonProperty annotation to add this data to an object whose JSON representation would be:

```
        "ipAndPort": [ 
          {
            "ipAddress": "1.2.3.4", 
            "ports": [80] 
          }
          ]
```

Where every ipAndPort object will have the same port (since there is only one received in the Json response body (aPort) and each ipAndPort object in the list will have one IP address from the list of ip addresses (someIps)

Or would I have to parse the data into a more similar object and then manually convert it to the ipAndPort format I need?

Comment: Do you think your expected JSON structure is syntactically correct??

Comment: You mean the response body I am getting? The JSON text I put is only a small segment of the entire response body. This is the only part of the JSON response I am having an issue with.

Comment: Yes. The reason is, you haven't specified any keyName for JsonObject inside your somIps valued JsonArray.

Comment: Also in your case I don't think `@JsonProperty` will help you much as `@JsonProperty`, tells Jackson `ObjectMapper` to map the JSON property name to the annotated Java field name.